# Equation of a Zero Truncated Poisson Model

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression

I want to apply a Zero Truncated Poisson regression in `R`. It works so far with the following Code:

```
require(VGAM)
```

> ```
> m1 <- vglm(howoften ~ TTCALL, family = pospoisson(), data = data)
> summary(m1)
>
> Call: vglm(formula = howoften ~ TTCALL, family = pospoisson(), data =
> data)
>
> Coefficients:
>
>            Estimate   Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)     
> (Intercept) 4.524128   0.017717    255.35   <2e-16 *** <br/>
>  TTCALL    -0.271246   0.005687    -47.69   <2e-16 ***
>
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Number of linear predictors:  1 
>
> Name of linear predictor: loge(lambda) 
>
> Dispersion Parameter for pospoisson family:   1
>
> Log-likelihood: Inf on 246 degrees of freedom
>
> Number of iterations: 14
> ```

I am not sure how the equation of the model has to look like. It think this should be the right one, but I am not sure about that:

```
howoften= exp(-0.27*TTCALL)+exp(4.52)
```